# Keeping a "reference" to a React state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that there are no pointers in Javascript.

I have the following problem though and I am wondering if there is a solution that eludes me. The solution maybe vanilla Javascript, or React.js hooks like the Context API (`useContext`), or combination of more Javascript and React, or the solution might be for me to go back to the drawing board.

*Please keep in mind I am introducing React.js to a frontend that used jQuery over prior years of development. My real situation is actually a multi-form wizard component that uses jQuery for Next/Previous stepping and animations.*

***Please do not think that I am actually trying to mix jQuery with React.js just do something like: `$('#myBtn').click` in jQuery.***

**My actual event in my software is not "a when trackMe changes event" so useEffect will not help here. Th software is a multi-form wizard, the actual event is the previous/next button press and the callback needs to know the current value of trackMe.**

Here is an a simple React Functional Component demonstrating my problem:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function App() {
    const [trackMe, setTrackMe] = useState('INIT');

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('trackMe change', trackMe);
    },[trackMe]);

    const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        setTrackMe(e.target.value);
    };

    const startEvent = () => {
        var trackMeVar = trackMe;
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('event complete, callback called');
            console.log('value of trackMe: ', trackMe); //always INIT even though state is changing
            console.log('value of trackMeVar: ', trackMeVar); //always INIT even though state is changing
        }, 1000);
    };

    function init() {
        console.log('init');
        $('#myBtn').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(startEvent, 1000);
        });
    }

    window.onload = init;

    return (
        <div>
            <input className="form-control" type="text" name="trackme"
                onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)} value={trackMe} />
            <button type="button" id="myBtn">Start Event</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The problem is my callback `startEvent` has its own scoped version of the `trackMe` state variable instead of the outer scope latest updated value, after state changes, in the `handleOnChange` function.

To see in action, just type in the textbox and state will change. Press the "Start Event" button to see that `trackMe` is always its initial value "INIT" within the event callback.

I believe the heart of an answer to my question is if there is anyway I can rewrite my event callback function so that the function contains the most recent value of my state variable `trackMe`.

Comment: hope my answer helps, let me know if you need more info,

Comment: @DhananjaiPai no your answer doesn't help with my particular scenario, thank you for trying though

Comment: I'm not entirely sure there is a way to achieve this as you currently have it set up. `trackMe` (and React state in general) isn't really going to interact with the outside world of jQuery and `window.onload` callbacks. Let me brainstorm if I can think of another way

Comment: @MitchLillie Yes I hear ya, I am not sure there is a solution in this situation either

Comment: @BrianOgden If there is a way, it is definitely not with hooks. Because your code violates the "rules of hooks" here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html . Still thinking...

Comment: You don't need JQuery to handle this properly. If I understood, you only want to pass current value of trackMe when the user clicks on the button. You can just add onClick event to the button element like this: 
onClick={() => setTimeout(() => startEvent(trackMe), 1000)}
and you can "pick" the trackMe value in startEvent function -> const startEvent = (track) => {.... use track instead of trackMe}

Comment: @NikolaRavic read the Italic and bold portions at the beginning of my question, specifically: "Please do not think that I am actually trying to mix jQuery with React.js just do something like: $('#myBtn').click in jQuery."

Comment: @MitchLillie hmmm what rules of Hooks am I violating, I am not calling Hooks from regular functions, I am checking a state value created by the useState hook in a regular JS function but...

Comment: @BrianOgden Yes, I did, but I was wondering if you are forced to use the JQuery to handle that particular button click or you can use onClick handler directly... Sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the value of `trackMe` in a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables), and read from it:

```
function App() {
  const [trackMe, setTrackMe] = useState('INIT');
  const track = useRef('INIT');

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
      console.log('trackMe before:', trackMe);
      setTrackMe(e.target.value);
      track.current = e.target.value // Sync the state value with the ref's current property
  };

  const startEvent = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('event complete, callback called');
          console.log('value of trackMe: ', track.current); // Read current value in the timeout callback
      }, 1000);
  };

  return (
      <div>
          <input className="form-control" type="text" name="trackme"
              onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)} value={trackMe} />
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setTimeout(startEvent, 1000)} id="myBtn">Start Event</button>
      </div>
  )
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-re73w)

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function)

Comment: I understand that, the `useEffect` is just there to show your the latest value of `trackMe`, you can omit it

Comment: The callback of the next/previous buttons have access to the current value, when you use a `ref`, can you please check the demo?

Comment: Looks promising, how is the "track" ref connected to trackMe, they seem like completely independent variables

Comment: I added comments to my code, you basically need to sync the state (`trackMe`) to the ref.

Comment: Also, a side note, if the next/previous buttons are clicked multiple times, and if you care only about the last time, so you will have to clear the previous timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

React setState(and useState callback) actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the documentation of setState.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

So,

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        console.log('trackMe before:', trackMe);
        setTrackMe(e.target.value);
        console.log('trackMe after: ', trackMe); // will not be updated synchronously
    };
```

to run the code everytime `trackMe` is changed you must use `useEffect()` hook

```
const startEvent = () => {
        var trackMeVar = trackMe;
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('event complete, callback called');
            console.log('value of trackMe: ', trackMe); // always INIT even though state is changing, because it is not run again when state is updated
            console.log('value of trackMeVar: ', trackMeVar); //always INIT even though state is changing, because it always stores the same trackMe variable
        }, 1000);
    };

useEffect(() => {startEvent()},[trackMe]); //calls startEvent everytime trackMe is updated, giving the required result
```

Refer [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

**Update**

You cannot get access to the react state if you add jQuery into the mix.
A possible solution is to use

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log('init');
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(startEvent, 1000); //should work as intended
}

<button type="button" id="myBtn" onClick={handleClick}>Start Event</button>
```

Comment: Well trackMe console.logs updated every time I type in the component textBox. Also my event it is not a when trackMe changes event so useEffect will not help here. As I explained in my question, the actually software is a wizard, the event is the previous/next button press and the callback needs to know the current value of trackMe

Comment: oh, wait, let me see

Comment: you will have to rewrite the click event, since the state variable updates cannot be accessed

Comment: Yes I believe that is probably at the heart of the answer to my question, how to rewrite the click event callback to have contain the state variable most recent update